# Getting Oracle Error ORA-06572 when calling Function with out parameter

Tags: oracle, function, call

I have tried many times to call below Oracle function that has Out parameter, and each time i get Error ORA-06572, Would you please provide me the best way to do this?

```
FUNCTION GET_NUMBER_TYPE (  P_MSISDN IN NUMBER,
                                P_CONTRACT_TYPE OUT BCC_CONTRACTS.CONTRACT_TYPE%TYPE)
                                RETURN BCC_CONTRACTS.CONTRACT_TYPE%TYPE
   IS
   BEGIN
      SELECT CON.CONTRACT_TYPE
        INTO P_CONTRACT_TYPE
        FROM BCC_CONTRACTS CON, BCC_SUB_NUMBERS SUB
       WHERE CON.CONTRACT_NO = P_MSISDN AND SUB.STATUS = 2;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No Data Found');
   END GET_NUMBER_TYPE;
```

Comment: What are the parameter values you are passing while calling the function? and from where?

Comment: @Nimesh Dear i just want the way to call such function, bear in mind that it have out parameter and ref cursor. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is no ref cursor in your function, it's a simple value select.
- If your function has an `OUT` parameter, you CANNOT use it inside SQL statement (that's why you get ORA-06572). I'm not even sure how did you try to use it. How would you set the second parameter in `select GET_NUMBER_TYPE(1, ...) from dual`?
- You ignore the exception. It's not exactly a good thing, but can lead you to some long debugging.
- You don't `return` anything from your function. Function should always return something, or you'll get an error.
- In fact, you don't even need `OUT` parameter, just return what you select.

  ```
  FUNCTION GET_NUMBER_TYPE (P_MSISDN IN NUMBER)
                              RETURN BCC_CONTRACTS.CONTRACT_TYPE%TYPE
  IS
  v_contract_type BCC_CONTRACTS.CONTRACT_TYPE%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT CON.CONTRACT_TYPE
      INTO v_contract_type
      FROM BCC_CONTRACTS CON, BCC_SUB_NUMBERS SUB
     WHERE CON.CONTRACT_NO = P_MSISDN AND SUB.STATUS = 2;
     return v_contract_type;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No Data Found');
       return NULL;
  END GET_NUMBER_TYPE;
  ```

Comment: Dear that's exactly what i'm looking for, and sorry for putting that the Function has ref cursor , it was a mistake , i have updated the question , thanks .